# Compare a column in one table against a whole other table?

Tags: sql, csv

I know that SQL joins exist but that is only for one column against another column in another table. Is there any way to do something similar with one column against a whole table? I'm trying to figure out if the people that exist within one organization are a certain kind of employee. The problem is I have all the people in a organization listed within a column in one table while the classification for people is scattered throughout various columns in another table.

Answer (score 1):

While I will answer this, I recommend you do one of those schoolkids tutorials on SQL. This question is at such a basic level you'll probably just get confused by the answers anyway...

From your question I would gather that the tables are probably modeled incorrectly to start with (not normalized well enough). But if you want to join a column to all the columns in another table you can do it in two ways:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.COLUMN_1 = T2.COLUMN_1
UNION ALL
SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_1 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.COLUMN_1 = T2.COLUMN_2
UNION ALL
... (just change the column name on each row)
```

(works best if you copy/paste this into Excel with a macro and a list of column names from table 2).

2) More complex: create a view or subquery where you first union all columns in table 2 one by one (hopefully they all have the same type!) and then join to the subquery, which now acts as a table with just one column.

3) Start pivoting table 2. Not going into that one, too complex for your current level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Basically if you have one Table and then you want to filter out some name from there and then you can use joins 
and the second part is yes you can add multiple conditions with the help of where clause.

and id you want to join on multiple conditions then also you can do with and condition